# How may we write a two language or bilanguage subject index? Like English & Persian index

Tags: xepersian, xindex

I'm using the XePersian package to prepare a book in Farsi. I want to create an index for the book in both Farsi and English languages. What is the best way to do so with existing latex packages?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `memoir` class provides for multiple indexes. See section 17.2 Index in the manual (`texdoc memoir`). I don't know about different languages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example with `imakeidx`. The index generation (with `makeindex`) is done by `imakeidx` itself, so there is no need to run `makeindex` separately.

Note: I don't know any Farsi myself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Mapping={}]{Amiri}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\makeindex[name=english,title={English Index}]
\makeindex[name=persian,title={Farsi Index}]

\begin{document}

\begin{latin}
  \section{Omar Khayyam}

  \index[english]{Omar Khayyam} \index[persian]{\rl{عمر خیّام}}

  Ghiyāth al-Dīn Abū al-Fatḥ ʿUmar ibn Ibrāhīm Nīsābūrī (18 May 1048
    – 4 December 1131), commonly known as Omar Khayyam (Persian:
    \rl{عمر خیّام}), was a polymath, known for his contributions to
  mathematics, astronomy, philosophy, and Persian poetry. He was born in
  Nishapur, the initial capital of the Seljuk Empire. As a scholar, he
  was contemporary with the rule of the Seljuk dynasty around the time
  of the First Crusade (Source: Wikipedia).

\printindex[english]
\end{latin}

\printindex[persian]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]